# Combining header (in a separate txt file) and data (in a separate csv file) in R to make a data set

Tags: r, csv, data.table

I have a txt file which has a list of headers and the type of value for each column as shown below:

header.txt:

```
airport string  
city    string  
country string
```

and the data as :

data.csv:

```
SYD SYD AU
CCU CCU IND
MSP MSP US
```

I would like to convert the data to:

```
airport city country
  SYD   SYD AU
  CCU   CCU IND
  MSP   MSP US
```

My idea was to read the header and data file separately, take only the column names from the header file, transpose them, save it as a separate csv file. 
The next step was to combine the two csv files.

I have used data.table to  read the file

```
 monthlyHeader <- fread("header.txt")
```

But the "airport" becomes header and "city" and " country"  are the values of the column "airport"

```
  airport string 
1  city  string 
2  country string 

monthlyHeader <- t(monthlyHeader)
```

the transpose of monthlyHeader does not give the desired result.

Is there a better way to implement this in R ?

Comment: just import both without headers and do a `colnames` assignment with first column of your data.frame with headers afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table` as requested, this can be achieved as follows

```
library(data.table)
header <- fread("header.txt", header = FALSE)
header
```

> ```
>         V1     V2
> 1: airport string
> 2:    city string
> 3: country string
> ```

```
data <- fread("data.csv", col.names = header$V1)
data
```

> ```
>    airport city country
> 1:     CCU  CCU     IND
> 2:     MSP  MSP      US
> ```

Or, in one line of code

```
data <- fread("data.csv", col.names = fread("header.txt", header = FALSE)$V1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For importing fixed-width files, I would recommend `read_fwf` from the `readr` package, which helps you solve most common problems with parsing fixed-width files. Here is an example of parsing your files via guessing column endings via the empty columns - there are other possible strategies if this fails on your full file:

```r
library(readr)
fwf <- "airport string  
city    string  
country string   "
fwf2 <- "SYD SYD AU
CCU CCU IND
MSP MSP US"

d1 <- read_fwf(fwf, fwf_empty(fwf, col_names = c("name", "type")))
d1
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>      name   type
#>     <chr>  <chr>
#> 1 airport string
#> 2    city string
#> 3 country string
```

The task of using the column names from this data frame is now quite trivial just by specifying them when we import the second file:

```r
d2 <- read_fwf(fwf2, fwf_empty(fwf2, col_names = d1$name))
d2
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   airport  city country
#>     <chr> <chr>   <chr>
#> 1     SYD   SYD      AU
#> 2     CCU   CCU     IND
#> 3     MSP   MSP      US
```